# How to open the terminator with 4 window?

Tags: terminator

I am using terminator. It is awesome to work with it. But thing is i want to custom the terminator to split the window as 4 or more while opening itself. Now i am splitting the window using the shortcut CTRL+SHIFT+O and CTRL+SHIFT+E.

Any idea to setup will be great.

Answer (score 6):

In Terminator you can right click and then choose "Preferences".

When you add a new layout (left button "add") terminator will add your current windows settings.

Give it a name and close the preferences window.

Now in `~/.config/terminator/config` your new layout is added.

You can now start terminator with:

```
terminator -l yourLayout
```

If you want terminator to always start with your layout, have a look at that file (`~/.config/terminator/config`). Should be easy to copy your settings to the `[default]` section.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit you terminator config file with profile configs and this will your default layout and you can just type **terminator** in terminal to start with 4 split session.

Copy paste the below configuration for 4 windows split in terminator

```
[global_config]
  title_hide_sizetext = True
  enabled_plugins = LaunchpadCodeURLHandler, APTURLHandler, LaunchpadBugURLHandler
  suppress_multiple_term_dialog = True
[keybindings]
[profiles]
  [[default]]
    cursor_blink = False
    font = DejaVu Sans Mono 9
    scrollback_infinite = True
[layouts]
  [[default]]

    [[[root]]]
      position = -4:0
      type = Window
      order = 0
      parent = ""
      size = 1072, 1884

    [[[grand]]]
      position = 536
      type = HPaned
      order = 0
      parent = root
    [[[left]]]
      position = 942
      type = VPaned
      order = 0
      parent = grand
    [[[right]]]
      position = 942
      type = VPaned
      order = 1
      parent = grand

    [[[terminal1]]]
      profile = default
      type = Terminal
      order = 0
      parent = left
    [[[terminal2]]]
      profile = default
      type = Terminal
      order = 1
      parent = left

    [[[terminal3]]]
      profile = default
      type = Terminal
      order = 1
      parent = right
      command = ""
    [[[terminal4]]]
      profile = default
      type = Terminal
      order = 0
      parent = right
[plugins]
```